# How to iterate all elements based on name attribute and modify the value in Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Below is my HTML snippet,

```
<div class="direct-service hide">
    ..   
    <input handle="input" type="hidden" name="./season" value="spring">
    <input handle="input" type="hidden" name="./season" value="">
    ...
</div>
```

I want to iterate all element inside *direct-service* class and look for .*/season* name attribute and check if the value is empty. If it is empty I need to modify the element as

```
<input handle="input" type="hidden" name="./season@Empty" value="">
```

I tried to get the value based name property with below code

```
$("input[name='./season']").val();
```

But it is giving me the value for first element and not giving me the second element. Seemed like I need to scan all element inside the div class. Could you anyone tell me the best way to manage this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .eq() function, example:

```
$("input[name='./season']").eq(0).val(); // Get first element
$("input[name='./season']").eq(1).val(); // Get second element
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `.map()` to iterate and return an array of all the values.

```
$("input[name='./season']").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Or if you want to do something to each of them, use `.each()`

```
$("input[name='./season']").each(function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
        $(this).setAttr("value", "");
    }
}).get();
```

Comment: Can I have this logic only when the div class direct-service hide is present?

Comment: Something like this? `$("div.direct-service.hide input[name='./season']")`

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar